# Unzipping a gzip file that contains a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, zip, gzip

I have just hit an endpoint and can pull down a gzip compressed file. 
I have tried saving it and extracting the csv inside but I keep getting errors around encoding whether I try casting from its current state in binary to utf-8/utf-16.

To write to the saved gzip I write in binary mode:

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=auth, stream=True)
with gzip.open('file.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Where r.content looks like:

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00f\x8dKM\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00A\x00\x00\x00RANKTRACKING_report_created_at_11_10_18_17_41-20181011-174141.csv\xec\xbdk\x8f\xe3V\x96\xae\xf9}\x80\xf9\x0f\ ... '
```

To extract the file on my machine manually I first have to extract to zip and then I can extract that to get the csv. I have tried the same there but ran into encoding errors there too.

Looking for a way to pull out this csv so I can print lines in python console.

Comment: Can you show the code that fails?

Comment: Don't use `gzip.open(...`, use only `open(...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a gzip file. That's a zip file. You are then taking the zip file that you retrieved from the URL, and trying to compress it again as a gzip file. So now you have a zip file inside a gzip file. You have moved one step further away from extracting the CSV contents, as opposed to one step closer.

You need to use [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html) to extract the contents of the zip file that you downloaded.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21121150)

Comment: API documentation specified that it was a Gzip which confused the hell out of me. Thanks for help. How did you recognize that it was a zip?

Comment: The "PK". Zip headers start with PK. (It stands for Phil Katz, who created the zip file format and the PKZip software.)

Comment: @Alex.K. It is now clear that my original answer, "That's not a gzip file. That's a zip file." in fact _exactly_ and _completely_ answered the question. As I had suspected.